# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' (never seen this error)

Tags: c++

I am kinda new to programming and have never seen this kind of error, so if someone can help me it would be appreciated. I tried to use string for numbers to compare digits to one another, but got this error and I guess it doesn't work :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    fstream f("telef.txt");

    f >> n;

    string numeriai;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        f >> numeriai;
        bool nice = false;
        int length = numeriai.length();
        for (int j=0; j<length; j++)
        {
            char ch = numeriai.at(j);
            char chh = numeriai.at(j+1);
            if (ch > chh)
            {
                nice = true;
            }
            else
            {
                nice = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nice = true)
        {
            cout << numeriai << endl;
        }
        for (int k=0; k<length; k++)
        {
            char ch = numeriai.at(k);
            char chh = numeriai.at(k+1);
            if (ch == chh)
            {
                nice = true;
            }
            else
            {
                nice = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nice = true)
        {
            cout << numeriai << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what character is `numeriai.at(j+1);` when `j == length-1` ?

Comment: The loop goes till `j` is 1 less than `length`. Then you do `numeriai.at(j+1);` which is basically `numeriai.at(length)` which is out of bounds.

Comment: it means two things, you have an index going out of range. And you don't have a catch(const std::out_of_range& e) exception handler to "nicely" handle your error.

Comment: An extension to the above comment: Sometimes allowing the program to crash IS the nicest way to handle an error. In the case of a logic error in the program, making the mistake obvious and forcing the programmer to address the mistake is one of the nicest things you can do for them.

Comment: Read the documentation for [`std::string::at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at). You would do well to go through the code you've written and look up the requirements for all of the functions that it calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a length of 10. That means your loop will loop until `j = 9`

```
for (int j=0; j<length; j++)
```

At that point, what happens with the following?

```
char ch = numeriai.at(j);
char chh = numeriai.at(j+1);
```

`ch` gets the value of the last character in the string (at index 9), but `chh` tries to read one past the last character. This results in your out of range error.

You probably want to loop one less time to account for this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++)
```

---

Also note that

```
if (ch > chh)
{
    nice = true;
}
else
{
    nice = false;
    break;
}
```

can be cleaned up to be

```
nice = ch > chh;
if(!nice) { break; }
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew what the problem was and I actually tried to put length-1, but my answer was wrong and I didn't think that the problem was with something else as well :D Thank you once more

Answer (score 0):

`::at()` throws the exception and you are not handling it in the following call and similar ones:

```
char chh = numeriai.at(j+1);
```